# In SSRS, how do I make a drop-down parameter visible only if a previous parameter has one option chosen?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a situation where I want to make  a drop-down parameter visible only if a previous multi-drop-down param. has one choice chosen(out of many choices).

[image]

Wht i've triedso far is to set the Default Val. for the drop-down parameter to be this:

```
=iif( Parameters!AccountIDs.Count >0 , 1, Nothing)
```

But it's not working.  any tips appreciated, thanks

Comment: If all of the parameters are based on a query results then you can make the input of Query2 set to the value of Paremeter1 and the input of Query3 can be set to the value of Paremeter2. The dependency will be sorted out based on the parameter chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to make a parameter disabled or enabled like this. (At least not without getting really complicated and hacking the page a bunch)

But you can make the second parameter have dynamic available options. Then make it just a sinlge option such as `"<Not applicable>"` and select that if the earlier parameter has multiple values.

You will need to create a dataset that returns the available parameters. Something like this might work:

```
SELECT
    '<Not Applicable>' AS ParameterValue
WHERE
    @ParamOneCount > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    SourceName
FROM
    someTable
WHERE
    @ParamOneCount = 1
```

(You could change replace the second `SELECT` with multiple selects to have multiple hard coded values.) Then in the parameters for this dataset, set one of the parameters to be called "ParamOneCount" and set its value to be `=Parameters!Account.Count`